# matlab user defined function, how to create and call them

Tags: matlab, user-defined-functions

I have written a code in matlab script. I need to finish it up by creating a Function for center.

Here is the sample code i written

```
while(1)        % infinite loop

trigger(obj); 
im=getdata(obj,1);   %get the image

trigger(obj); 
im1=getdata(obj,1);  % the first time triggering occurs the image is just
                              % noise. Thus the 2nd image is used.
b=rgb2gray(im1);      % convert to grayscale
a=roicolor(b,[100:118]);  %define a region of interest
a=~a;

c=center(a);
                  % use disp(c) to see the values, while testing
if (c(2)>190)
fwrite(ser,'r');  % send move right
elseif (c(2)<170 && c(2)>10)
fwrite(ser,'l');
elseif c(2)<170
fwrite(ser,'l'); % stop
```

now in this **center(a)** its not a predefined function in matlab, its a user defined one.

**The function center(a) that I have used is not an inbuilt function. I would suggest you write a function for center which I can work on**

I want you people to help me to create a function in matlab and to call the user defined function, when ever I needed.

Comment: I would suggest that YOU write a function for `center` and we'll help you get it right.  That's the usual orientation of activity here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a file called `center.m` put all your code in there and start the file (at the top) with something like:

```
function c = center(a);
```

Comment: please help me by typing and giving